# Monitor an AWS RDS DB intance with Zabbix

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-rds, zabbix

Currently, I'm trying to monitor an AWS RDS DB Instance (MySQL MariaDB) with Zabbix but I'm experiencing several troubles:

- I have the script placed into the externalscripts folder on Zabbix Server and template (https://github.com/datorama/zabbix_rds_template) with my aws access data properly filled. The host is already added as well but Zabbix doesn't retrieve data from the AWS RDS Instance (all graphs display no data [See the graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PwEV.png) ).

How could I check if the zabbix Server is able to reach the RDS instance to start to discard things?

Do anyone know the correct way to add AWS RDS host in Zabbix?

Any suggestion or advice is welcome always.

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards
KV.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the Zabbix Log? Maybe you don't use a user with enough permission. Try to run the script in the Zabbix server shell.

Have your Zabbix Server in AWS? if yes, set it a role with read access to CloudWatch and RDS.

Also, I don't like use credentials in a script, I prefer configure it with AWS CLI.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Here, there is another example to monitoring any AWS Cloudwatch metrics with Zabbix that I use.

https://www.dbigcloud.com/cloud-computing/230-integrando-metricas-de-aws-cloudwatch-en-zabbix.html